# Pig 0.12.0 over Hadoop 2.3.0 on Windows 2008 r2 x64

Tags: bash, hadoop, apache-pig, msys, mintty

I've build Hadoop 2.3.0 Src successfully on windows 2008 r2 x64. The NameNode, DataNode, ResourceManager and NodeManager all work fine now.

I recompiled the Pig-0.12.0 Src using Apache Ant with `ant clean jar-withouthadoop -Dhadoopversion=23` parameters.
Then I copied the recompiled Pig dir to Hadoop Home dir, and set all the environment variables.

I used Mintty, MSYS to open a Bash Shell Window, and typed `pig -x local or pig`.

The screen shows lots of [INFO]... messages and finally `grunt>` shell.
But whenever I type any Pig command, it doesn't react.

Has anyone run Pig run time successfully over Hadoop 2.3.0 on windows?
Any possible suggestion??

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved my problem by directly using bash.exe instead of mintty /bin/bash -l.
The local mode and mapreduce mode of pig runtime all work fine now.
I note here in case of the same situation from someone.